# LinkedIn share requirements to display BIG image

Tags: javascript, html, share, linkedin-api

**My question is: why image is small and how to make it big?**

I have implemented linkedIn share. 
For that I have added meta tags: `og:title` `og:image` `og:description` `og:url`.

Everything is working but my image is small.

- [Small image example](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55018677/linkedin-share-big-image)
- [Big image example](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https://itbrief.com.au/story/idc-top-10-trends-for-australia-s-digital-transformation)

We have asked linkedIn about that and answer was to check image aspect ratio but it is fine. And image aspect ratio is not what cause the problem.

**We have tested different images** (sizes, dimension, simple images, colorful images, etc). **Nothing helped**.

**Probably it is different origin issue**. Try to make sure that your site and your images are served from same origin.

Comment: Hey Arseniy-II, I know this is really annoying that it does not work. But may I know what are the dimensions (in pixels) of an image that you are using while sharing the Link?

Comment: We have tried recommended ratio: 1.91:1 . And it didn't work

Comment: Alright! that's correct, I have posted an answer. Hope that helps you somehow.

Comment: Excellent question!  Just curious, was the upvoted answer below right?  Did that work?  (Maybe mark it as right?)  Thanks again!

Comment: @HoldOffHunger it is helpful in a some way but it isn't right. It didn't help to solve the problem. I believe issue was that image and site had different origin. like site url was https://some-site.com and image url was https://some-image-url.com and when we changed image url issue was solved

Answer (score 1):

It has to work well, also you might have taken care of all minute required things.

Still, I would like to help you with some insights which I think is really needed to make it work as per the LinkedIn's guideline and my experience with using it.

## Info. from LinkedIn:

**Below are the og: tags that must exist and their correct format:**

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />`

Here are the image requirements specific to the LinkedIn sharing module:

- Max file size: 5 MB
- Minimum image dimensions: 1200 (w) x 627 (h) pixels
- Recommended ratio: 1.91:1

**Note**: If the image meets the requirements, but it still does not appear in updates on LinkedIn, your website may be blocking us from pulling the image or the image may be located on a protected directory or website.

## My Suggestion:

You might have taken good care of aspect ratio, but **the catch** here is the **minimum dimension** and the **maximum allowed file size** of an image that they mentioned.

I would check if I am having a **minimum dimension as 1200 (w) x 627 (h) pixels**.

Also, would take care of the file size, that is it must not be larger than 5 MB.

Along with these things, I would also look for if I am having META's - `og:image:width` and `og:image:height`.

***Example:***

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1920" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="780" />
```

## Update:

If all of the things are set as mentioned above, you may wanna try clearing the browser's cache or try same it in an incognito(private) window.

Also, verify if you have URL encoded/decoded correctly while testing in an inspector tool or getting a preview when posting the URL.

I hope this helps you. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for answer! We need some time to implement everything ant check it. Hope all will work! :)

Comment: Welcome! Sure take your time :)

Comment: @divy3993 We added the image:width and image:height og tags and still it doesnt work. Our image is 88kb and its dimensions are 1201:628(1.91:1) so fulfilling the ratio, minimum width/height and file size requirements, still not working.

Also if you check the big image example arseniy posted, the image is smaller than minimum and still it works. Also weird is that on https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/ it works just fine but when you go to post it, the image gets small

Comment: Everything seems fine now. Can I ask for one more favor? Can you share the live link of your website(page)? Also, you might have tried already but I would suggest to clear your browser cache or try it in an incognito(private) window once.

Comment: Cache is may be the reason. I saw url displayed small image and after some time same url displayed big image. May you please add that moment to you answer? And also please mention that url should be encoded and decoded properly. We have had some issue with "=" character in our url too. Just in case some one have same problems.

Comment: Ok it is working for some and not for others. May it be some issue with server speed?

Comment: Oh, that may be the issue, but still I am always doubtful with the caches. So the one who are getting in their system correctly might have not opened LinkedIn for a while. So it's not just your browsers cache but also LinkedIn's cache or their servers cache.

Comment: I would appreciate if you will check this links (they are almost identical but linkedin treats them differently)
[works](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http://sourcr-staging-740740721.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com/recruiter/recruiter-test/review/candidate/UGxhY2VtZW50OjQ)
[doesn't work](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http://sourcr-staging-740740721.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com/recruiter/rikki-carmichael/review/employer/UGxhY2VtZW50OjE1)

Comment: Hey @Arseniy-II, can you pl. check now. You have done all the things correct, there is nothing needed to be changed in code. I have tried to scrap it multiple times using the same tool- LinkedIn Post Inspector. You can check here: https://i.imgur.com/b4RUYm5.gif

Comment: This link is working now. Am I right it is linkedIn cache and we just need to wait?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I am facing the same issue currently for one of my page in my project.

Comment: @divy3993, Thank a lot for your help!

Comment: We have tried to wait. And tried new images but all new one are small too. So it is not about cache.

Comment: @Arseniy-II, faced the same. Good to know that, I am not the only one. :)

Comment: @divy3993
We have tested different images (sizes, dimension, simple images, colorful images, etc). Nothing helped.
There is definitely some additional layer. We have changed the way how our server serves image and have had some progress but we still not sure what was the issue.

Comment: well at least you see an image, I get nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem on my wordpress website and blog2social plugin. all social websites like facebook, instagram, twitter are getting my post images, linkedin displays a gray box.  linkedin link inspector finds the picture correctly from og:image meta tag. also my posts image size was : 1000x500 pixel.  I saw that linkedin required ration 1.91:1  . so I changed my images post to 1000x525.  I used to have 1170x600 but that has a problem with instagram. so I reduced the width to 1000. I don't think the problem being with image size because randomely some posts are shared with correct image. but most of the time the post do not have image.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not about image size or ratio. We have had same images with same set of meta tags working correctly and incorrectly. So it is not fixed

Comment: What we found is that it is important how your images are served exactly. Try to serve image from same domain as your site.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is different origin issue. Try to make sure that your site and your images are served from same origin.

Like site url is `some-site.com` and image url is `some-image-url.com`. Try to change `some-image-url.com` to `some-site.com/image`