# How does the share-offsite url determine what size image to use?

Tags: linkedin-api

We have the ability current to share current articles on our site by clicking on the sharing icon. This loads up a URL like:

https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Fbuild-to-suit-leases-0419%2F

What's odd, is that the image that is loaded up from the OG:Image sometimes is very large while other times it's displayed as a small icon/banner layout. But in either case, the image is the exact same size and format which is used. The browser we use doesn't make a difference. I've also found that if I wait for the linked cache to clear and try to share the link again, it can give me a different layout.

Is there something else I can provide in that URL to specify the desired layout?

Answer (score 0):

I think this was already answered here:
[LinkedIn share requirements (BIG image)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55018677/linkedin-share-requirements-big-image/55293510#55293510)

But

Take a look at this link
https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en

So the recommended ratio of your image should be 1.91:1.

Do you have a working link for the URL you want to share?

I had problems before with it because we had something generating dynamic images and that was causing linkedin to display them little.

You can also add more meta tags to it like:

`og:image:width` - The number of pixels wide.

`og:image:height` - The number of pixels high.

More info about extra meta tags can be found here
http://ogp.me/