# Sharing on LinkedIn shows a giant image

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, share

I'm having some trouble with sharing function on linked in. I'm using the 'https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=' url in a share button on one of our websites. But when I'm trying to share it, the image that shows in the LinkedIn preview are very big.

I've checked that it recieves our og:width and og:height and assumed it should use that? When inspection the height and width set in the image are correct.

I don't have reputation enough to embed images, so here are a couple images with description: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ioEX.jpg

All in all, this gives a horrible user experience. Any suggestions would be appereciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @5377037 Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure how to limit it anymore. From what i can gather it seems others have the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55018677/linkedin-share-requirements-to-display-big-image/55293510#55293510
But tried the various suggestions, doesn't seems to apply to what I'm facing.